# Git: git pull - start from specific commit until the latest commits skipping 1 commit?

Tags: git, laravel, bitbucket, git-pull, git-fetch

How can I pull from a branch to start fetching on a specific commit?

Suppose, I have these branches:
`branch1` and `oldbranch1`

`branch1` is the rollback version of `oldbranch1`

And suppose, `oldbranch1` have these commits:

- commit_5
- commit_4
- commit_3 (merge `somebranch` to `oldbranch1`)
- commit_2
- commit_1

And on `branch1`:

- commit_2
- commit_1

Now I want to get the updates from `oldbranch1` skipping the `commit_3` from `oldbranch1` as it contains wrong merges that deletes the changes from `commit_2` and `commit_1`

How can I do it? is there any magic commands for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping a commit means mainly a [`git rebase --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--i):

- you make a `tmp` branch on top of `oldbranch1` ([`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) `tmp oldbranch1`)
- you `rebase -i branch1` that `tmp` branch, replaying each commit except `commit3` that you can drop
- you `reset --hard` `branch1` to the new `tmp` HEAD.

The last step means: moving (forcing) `branch1` HEAD to `tmp`, but since the rebase only added new (rewritten) commits to `branch1`, you should be able to simply do:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge tmp
```

That should make a fast-forward merge of `tmp` to `branch1`, moving simply `branch1` HEAD to where `tmp` is.

Then a simple `git push` (or `git push -u origin branch1` if `branch1` was never pushed before) will be enough.

Comment: is it `branch1` that I need to `rebase`?  as `branch1` doesn't have the wrong `commit` yet, or should I do `rebase -i commit_3` inside `tmp` branch?

Comment: You rebase TMP (your current branch) on top of branch1. That is what git rebase branch1 mlea'e

Comment: thanks! this is awesome. I successfully rewritten the history now. I'm just confused with the last step:

_`reset --hard branch1 to the new tmp HEAD.`_

since `tmp` is on my local, and `branch1` is behind some commits from the rebased `tmp`, should I `git push -f origin branch1`?  or if possible can you rewrite the third step to a more newbie friendly?

Comment: @DexterBengil i have edited the answer to expand on that last step.